# Summing up duration in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:
Bitcoin Sell and Buy prices, Date is in OLE format.

```
Date            Sell        Buy
43031.57567     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57564     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57561     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57558     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57555     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57552     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57549     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57546     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57544     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57541     5720.65     5770.65
43031.57537     5718        5768
43031.57534     5718        5768
43031.57531     5718        5768
43031.57528     5718        5768
43031.57524     5718        5768
43031.57522     5718        5768
43031.57519     5718.45     5768.45
43031.57516     5718.45     5768.45
43031.57512     5718.45     5768.45
43031.57509     5717.55     5767.55
43031.57506     5717.55     5767.55
43031.57504     5716.65     5766.65
4.3031.57501    5716.65     5766.65
```

I would like to analyze the average time it would take me to "overcome" a specific spread (e.g Buy-Sell or Sell-Buy), for example, spread = 20.
I'm using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import datetime as dt

OLE_TIME_ZERO = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0)
def ole(oledt):
    return OLE_TIME_ZERO + dt.timedelta(days=float(oledt))

spread = 20
counter = 0 
time = 0

df = pd.read_csv("C:/P/testing33.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = index + 1
    df_slice = df[a::]
    for index1, row1 in df_slice.iterrows():
        if row["Buy"] - row1["Sell"] > spread:
            time = time + ole(row["Date"]) - ole(row1["Date"]) 
            counter += 1
            break
    for index2, row2 in df_slice.iterrows():    
        if row["Sell"] - row2["Buy"] > spread:
            time = time + ole(row["Date"]) - ole(row2["Date"])
            counter += 1
            break

avg_time = time/counter
```

The logic behind it is to stop the "for" loop at the first time that the diff between Sell and Buy is greater than 20.
I'm receiving the following error:

```
time = time + ole(row["Date"])- ole(row1["Date"])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Can you please help understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems your `ole(row["Date"])` function is returning a `datetime` type and your trying to add an `int` to this. So you have a type mismatch

Comment: You're going to need to either convert your time variable to a datetime object, or if you somehow want to do it with integers, convert your datetime objects to integers. I'd recommend the first one because the second one doesn't make sense.

Comment: At the end I would like having a number which represents the “amount” of minutes. The type of the object doesn’t really matter. Any suggestions?